# DNS natting on Cisco 6502e IOS 12.2

Tags: cisco, nat

We sell internet BW to small businesses, Because of how caching & peering services are configured our customers can only benefit from our local GGC and akamai node, with speed and performance only if it they use our DNS service. But despite multiple requests our clients use global google DNS services (8.8.8.8) or their own internal DNS servers and then complain about not getting decent speed or high latency. We keep telling them but it's not making any difference. One of the things we did to some of our clients who are connected through Mikrotik CCR routers is NAT their DNS requesting. Doesn't matter whatever DNS server they are using, we NAT the DNS requests to use our own DNS Servers. So far, in the last month or so, we haven't had any problems. We want to do the same thing Cisco switches/routers, Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Why not policy-route DNS to your Mikrotiks and NAT it there.  It might be better than maintaining two custom solutions to the same problem.  I am bound to say though, that if you were my provider, I'd leave you and find another.

Comment: My understanding was that some customers have a Mikrotik as CPE, other customers have a Cisco CPE. But then again, I now realize there is a reference to a cat6k in the title... so confused now. OP please clarify?

Comment: Please read my comments to the answer posted below.

Comment: I don't see how those comments address my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/12214771/destination-nat-inside-outside-dns-traffic

Also, as someone has mentioned, if I was your customer, I would leave. Altering customers' traffic without their consent is big no-no. Beside, you're selling Internet BW. If they're using other DNS, that would mean they generate more traffic and they have to pay more isn't it?

Anyway, good luck.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not as simple as that. A very small % of users actually use private DNS, which is fine we are not making policy that users should use our DNS or we don't want to force others to use our DNS. But these users who don't use our DNS, they use their private DNS or google DNS and also complain about high latency to akamai traffic  or other peers we have. The way these peers work is that our DNS gets whitelisted with their node for us to able to use them - we don't make the rules, that's how they work.

Comment: They won't accept any third party DNS only DNS server who are directly peered to their nodes. We have been trying to explain to this clients that in order for them to get good latency to akamai or similar peers they need to use our DNS. We had countless meetings and over the phone conversation and we can't seem to make them understand. They are not technically proficient enough to understand this. But that's not going to stop them from complaining. We are trying to do this as an extreme measure. We don't benefit from this at all.

Answer (score 1):

How about giving them a demo? "Look how slow this is... now I change the DNS on this PC to xx.x.x.x and I download the same content again, look how fast it is now".
That, or raise your prices with 2% and give a 2% discount to those who use your DNS. Or a free T-shirt. Whatever works.